# How can I use value of each column instead variable $cols in setCellValue function?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

[([phpspreadsheet][1](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) I am using CodeIgniter framework. I am trying to convert the data using spreadsheet API. I want all agents in the column head, for that format is A1 = agent1, B1 = agent2. Using foreach and for loop I want to make $col variable dynamic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjzpP.png)

Image attached at starting of the description.

**ERROR Encountered**:

> Cell coordinate must not be absolute.
>   At line  $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($cols, $agent->firstname);

```
$cols1= 'B1';
$cols2='C1';
$cols3='D1';
$cols4='E1';
$cols5='F1';
$cols6='G1';
$cols7='H1';
$cols8='I1';
$cols9='J1';
$cols10='K1';
$cols11='L1';
$cols12='M1';
$cols13='N1';
$cols14='O1';
$cols15='P1';
$cols16='Q1';
$cols17='R1';
$cols18='S1';
$cols19='T1';
$cols20='U1';
$cols21='V1';
$cols22='W1';
$cols23='X1';
$cols24='Y1';

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'DATES');    
$cnt = count($agent_list);
foreach ($agent_list as $agent) {
    //echo $agent->firstname;
    for($i = 1; $i <= $cnt ; $i++){
        $cols = '$cols'.$i;
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($cols, $agent->firstname);
    }   
}     

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
```

Comment: You're trying to get cell '$cols'.$i, which isn't a valid Excel cell reference... it's missing a row number

Comment: @RaminRezazadeh Not working after adding row number as 1.  `$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($cols . 1, $agent->firstname);`